# Measuring AC current with a current transformer and ADC

Tags: adc, current-measurement, rms

I'm looking at using a current transformer (CT) to measure 50hz sinusoidal AC current with a microcontroller's ADC.

Is there a way to measure the RMS or average of an AC signal with good response without taking many samples with the ADC? I'd like to minimize the number of samples required by the ADC by using external filtering or other circuitry if possible. I have seen there are AC to RMS IC's available from Analog Devices but these seem to be in short supply and I feel as though there would be another non-proprietary solution.

I've found there are two popular ways of transforming the AC into a non-negative fluctuating voltage signal:

1. DC voltage offset to one side of the CT ([example 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/413976/ct-measuring-circuit-with-pic) [example 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333778/ac-current-measurement-with-atmega328))
2. Use a precision rectifier ([example](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Operational_Amplifiers_and_Linear_Integrated_Circuits_-_Theory_and_Application_(Fiore)/07%3A_Nonlinear_Circuits/7.02%3A_Precision_Rectifiers))

And there are two popular ways of converting that non-negative fluctuating signal into a measurement:

1. Measure with an ADC at a high frequency (100-1000hz) and calculate the RMS current.
2. Use an RC filter to convert the fluctuating signal into a average value.

My problem with any combination of these methods is that either the response time is slow to current changes or there is ripple introduced to the ADC reading in the case of the RC filter, or the ADC measurement becomes resource intensive for the MCU if continuous monitoring of the current is required.

Comment: What response time are you looking for and how much cpu time and samplerate is available?

Comment: If no harmonics, you can just sample at 2 times (with phase=0 and phase=90°).

Comment: Otherwise, 6, 11, or 21 samples per period (under timer interrupt) and run the DFT program.

Comment: _"Is there a way to measure the RMS or **average of an AC signal**"_ - average is easy - it's always zero :). What is the purpose of this measurement?

Comment: A smart meter I worked on used 16x sampling (800 Hz) and computed RMS from that. That gives you a mean latency of half a cycle (10 ms) plus the compute time. You can't really talk about an rms value of an AC waveform over any time less than a full cycle anyway. With a bit of cleverness, you can trim the calculation down from the obvious brute force way.

Comment: You may want to use an SAR ADC (or an MCU with one) if the one you are using is sigma-delta. Sigma-delta ADCs are more accurate but slower while SAR ADCs are faster but less accurate. When I was working for an electricity meter manufacturer we were mainly using SAR ADCs with a rate of around 2.4 kHz due to the requirement of measuring up to the 20th harmonic. Oh, by the way, CTs require a proper burden resistor so you may want to think about using a shunt instead. Just saying.

Comment: 100-1000Hz is really not a high sample frequency at all.

Comment: What current waveform are you dealing with? It's a simpler problem if it's sinusoidal. It's harder if you want a true RMS value for a non-sinusoidal waveform. In the latter case you won't get the correct result from a precision rectifier/RC filter combination.

Comment: @GrahamNye the waveform is 50hz sinusoidal.

Comment: @Jeroen3 - I'm more interested in alternative approaches than achieving a set criteria in this case, but the step response I'm looking at now with an RC filter is 0.4s. Less than 0.1s would be preferable.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  - I don't think I see why a shunt would be preferable. Could you elaborate on how a shunt would reduce the number of samples or improve measurement response time?

Comment: @BruceAbbott - The purpose is to measure the AC current flowing through the conductor for the purposes of current consumption management. Note it's not power management, we're only concerned with current. Yes, I guess I should have said the average of the absolute AC signal.

Comment: @Luke well, using a shunt may not affect the response time, of course. Because it's almost all about the ADC you are using. And what I said about ADC types still applies. But a CT is not accurate as a shunt. And you can't simply increase the burden resistor to get higher sample output voltage and therefore higher accuracy because you'll lose linearity. That's why I said "proper burden resistor should be used". As I said, just saying. It's just a geneal suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... the response time is slow to current changes ...

This is a circuit that can give the "peak voltage" (positive or negative) every "cycle" and/or "half cycle".

If there are no harmonics ... and voltage on the CT "enough" ...
You could use also a "synchronized sampler" to "sample" peak voltage value.
For this goal, use a "phase" shifter of 90°, followed by a comparator.
Just sample with the ADC on the edges of the comparator, this will give the "peak" value (positive or negative).
See the last part of my answer in this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/619418/differential-capacitive-transducer/619436#619436).

[image]