# Power current transformer performance: not getting expected output

Tags: current, transformer

We are designing Power CT. The circuit is below:

[image]

When I pass 230 V line from the coil I should get 3.6 V at the end of D7, but I am getting 360 mV.

What are the changes I need to make to get the appropriate values?

Comment: Please include your circuit at the other end of CON4. What's the turns ratio of your CT and what's the primary current?

Comment: Why do you use rectifiers for getting a non-linear output?

Comment: I'm using Power CT of 175:1 @winny

Comment: Thanks. That answered one out of two questions I asked.

Comment: Are these values correct? You have 147uF of capacitance and no burden resistance? Where do you expect to develop said voltages?

Comment: @Stiddily Good question. In some CT, the burden resistor is already wired. But for some others, it is not.

Comment: Ah, I'm used to small 200:1 CTs for SMPS. I imagine the built in ones would be a little beefier. To add to winny's questions we'd need the burden resistance value as well.

Comment: @winny  my output current will be 5-30A. we are using it in energy meters.

Comment: Will be? What was it when you got 360 mV output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the behavior (CT example) of your circuit (0 -> 10 A).

Problems I see :

- Output voltage is non-linear, specifically for low-currents,
- Simulating it (with R5 higher than 10 kOhm leads to some problems),
- Output (slow) is "stable" after, at least, more than 1 second,
- There is some ripple, specifically at high currents,
- ...
- What is the function of TL431? (Except for limiting voltage at the output)
- Function of diode at output?
- ...

[image]

And here from 0 to 100 A, ...

[image]

Change of R5 value, ... (0 to 100 A)

[image]

You should use my answer in [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/619945/measuring-ac-current-with-a-current-transformer-and-adc/619951#619951), somewhat adapted and simplified. Use of differential "calculator", and sample/hold (at rising or falling time) which can be replaced by a ADC interupted "software" sampling. The time delay is 10 ms at max, without filtering ... No "ripple".

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the brief information regarding this.